# Google Webmaster Tool Crawl Site Errors increase in not fount 404 Errors

Tags: .htaccess, google-search-console, google-crawlers

> Google detected a significant increase in the number of URLs that
>   return a 404 (Page Not Found) error. Investigating these errors and
>   fixing them where appropriate ensures that Google can successfully
>   crawl your site's pages.

And Let me know why google gives such Errors while crawl that website. I would like to keep in the notice that as I have rewrite the rules for the .php pages

Where I am doing wrong with the internal links between pages and content? As I have updated and correct the links after getting this message from webmaster staff team.

Kindly Check and investigate for the internal links and confirm me if I have missed something again?

Kindly Advice.

I will appreciate.

Comment: Hi. Can you please clarify your question as I am not sure what your problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just find broken links and fix them

you can then mark these 404 pages as Fixed in Webmaster Tools